# Using pointers in linked lists

Tags: c, pointers

I am aware of how to use pointers in order to point to other objects such as arrays, but in the scheme of knowing how to use them in linked lists, I am confused. For Example:

```
 struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *next;
}
typedef struct node Node
```

And assume that later on in the program, dataList is set to the address of the first node of a list that holds these data in this order: 25,30,45,60,65,80,90

I am to write C statements that set ptr1 to the address of the node holding 45 and set ptr2 to the address of the node holding 80.

Given that dataList is initially the head of the list, my idea was:

```
  ptr1= dataList.next.next
```

but I am sure that is incorrect formatting or I also thought that

```
ptr1->next->next
```

might be correct, 
but again, I am not sure.

Comment: ptr1= (dataList.next)->next

Comment: `ptr1= dataList->next->next`,Assuming dataList is the pointer to the head element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr1->next` is equivalent to `(*ptr1).next`, i.e. it gets the member called `next` from the struct that `ptr1` points to.

Structure dereference ("member b of object pointed to by a")    `a->b`

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `dataList`, `ptr1` and `ptr2` are pointers to struct node. So it should be `ptr1 = dataList->next->next`. `->` is just a shortcut for a pointer to reference to the member of the struct it points to.

Answer (score 1):

dataList is the one that is holding the start address of the list. So you access them all using dataList variable. Your idea of using `->next->next` to point to 45 is correct just that it should be `ptr1 = dataList->next->next`, but we dont go about doing `->next->next->next...` all over to get every element, but use a pointer to hold every next address and loop till we have got desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `next->next->next` will work, but that isn't what we would want to achieve by using linked lists. Compare the `info` of each node while traversing and point `ptr1` and `prt2` to the node where you want to point. A sample code is given below.

PS: I am just a beginner, correct me if I am wrong.

```
if ( dataList != 0 ) {
        while ( dataList->next != 0)
        {
            dataList = dataList->next;
            if (dataList->info == 25 ) {
                ptr1 = dataList;
            }
            if (dataList->info == 80 ) {
                ptr2 = dataList;
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following declaration for dataList

```
   struct node anode1, anode2, anode3, anode4, anode5, anode6, anode7;
   struct node *dataList = &anode1;

   anode1.info = 25;
   anode1.next = &anode2;

   anode2.info = 30;
   anode2.next = &anode3;

   anode3.info = 45;
   anode3.next = &anode4;

   anode4.info = 60;
   anode4.next = &anode5;

   anode5.info = 65;
   anode5.next = &anode6;

   anode6.info = 80;
   anode6.next = &anode7;

   anode7.info = 90;
   anode7.next = NULL;

   printf("Third node = %d\n", dataList->next->next->info); // prints 45
   printf("Sixth node = %d\n", dataList->next->next->next->next->next->info); // prints 80
```